# Не работает терминал в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Ошибка:

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [powershell.exe] in C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\equations

Error running process: CreateProcess failed. Code 2


See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.
```

Answer (score 1):

При подобной проблеме я скачал установщик последней версии powershell с  https://aka.ms/PSWindows и установил её. При установке в PATH прописалось `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\` и терминал заработал. В целом, проблема была именно в пути к powershell

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй зайти в File > Settings > Terminal и выставить путь до cmd,
(обычно это: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)

Comment: Теперь у меня другая ошибка, пишет что нет такого каталога

Comment: попробуй поискать в системе cmd.exe и указать путь до него в pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите переменные среды, которые выставлены на вашем компьютере.
Вас интересует `PSModulePath`.
У меня выставлены следующие переменные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Укажи фактический путь до cmd
Просто к ярлыку запуска будет достаточно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с той же проблемой. Установка переменной окружения Path "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 " мне помогла. Не забудьте перезапустить приложение (если вы используете PyCharm)

*thanks to @BepUnic*

Comment: ваш ответ ведь по сути не добавляет ничего нового к уже [существующему ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1541132/178576)?